# How to Add Compound Indices in Shark Orm

Tags: ios, database, dbaccess

I understand how to define one property indices in SharkORM per the documentation

```
+ (SRKIndexDefinition *)indexDefinitionForEntity {
    SRKIndexDefinition* idx = [SRKIndexDefinition new];
    [idx addIndexForProperty:@"name" propertyOrder:SRKIndexSortOrderAscending];
    [idx addIndexForProperty:@"age" propertyOrder:SRKIndexSortOrderAscending];
    return idx;
}
```

From my understanding the above will create one index on name, and another on age. However, what if I want to create a compound index (i.e. one that encompasses name first, and then age). If the above code is doing that, then my question is instead how do I define more than one index for a model?

To put it another way how would I define the following two indices in SharkORM?

- [name, age]
- [name, location]

Comment: Okay after some additional investigation I see there is a method called addIndexForProperty: propertyOrder:secondaryProperty:secondaryOrder, but what about if I want three properties? Is it just not supported?

Comment: You can add it and send me a pull request?  A future version may change to be an array of indexed properties, but you would be the first person to raise the idea of a three part index and current efforts are far more concerned in modernising the orm ready for swift 4.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. I'll concede that three property indices are rare, but it was surprising that it wasn't written to support an indefinite number of indices. I can take a look and see how much frustration supporting that would cause. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No problem, yes I agree that there are many instances of things where the api should be rationalised and changed but we pick our battles one part at a time.  You are very welcome to adapt the code to support more, or an array of indexes, that part of the code is not that horrific to look through.

Comment: Pull request to include the feature: https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm/pull/89

Comment: Awesome, looks good.  I'll just run it through some tests and merge it in with some other changes i've been working on.  Thank you for contributing.